# Why does vector and OnMove function takes different axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I am following a tutorial on unity website. Below is a code snippet.

```
void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
{
    Vector2 movementVector = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

    movementX = movementVector.x;
    movementY = movementVector.y;
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);
    rb.AddForce(movement); 
}
```

Here, I am trying to move a sphere. I have taken input from keyboard in movementX and movementY. My sphere will not fly above, so y axis should be zero. Can anyone tell me why Y axis of onMove is Z axis of vector 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why Y axis of onMove is Z axis of vector 3?

it's because the Input in your case is 2D --move to left or right is considered the X axis input(like keyboard buttons A/D in games) and forward or backward is the Y axis input(like W/S in the keyboard also)-- for example if you pressed W key, your input will be like vector2(0,1) and means y axis value is 1...etc. so this was the input now we want the sphere moves forward when we press the W key, as you are working in a 3D space the forward/backward is the Z axis. so we need to put the y value of the input in the object velocity to move forward (z axis) that's why the example above puts the y input in z axis to make the sphere moves forward/backward.

if your code was like this :

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, movementY ,0.0f );
rb.AddForce(movement);
```

when you press W your sphere will fly and when you press S your sphere will dive.
And if is like this:

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY );
rb.AddForce(movement);
```

your object will move forward/backward according to your y input value, and left/right according to your x input value.

rather than check if W or S or A or D key is pressed and determine to move right when D was pressed... you just link movementX input to your object X-axis movement and movementY input to your object Z-axis movement.

> it's just about what do you want to do. also you can customize your inputs and your objects movements as you want.